# How to set the webview scroll default to the bottom in android

Tags: android, webview

I want to set the webview scroll to bottom as default in android. in screenshot the last line i am not able to see without scroll. i want to see the last line of that content of webview

[image]

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: make size of scroll view small

Comment: OH MY GOD!! Why does an Android application look like it's trying to mimic an iOS application? And to make matters even worse, all elements are badly misaligned... if you have no time to polish UI, it's better to stick to Android defaults...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question , use the [pageDown(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pageDown%28boolean%29)

> bottom = true to jump to bottom of page

Do this till this api returns false.

---

If I may, can I suggest a much better method of doing this?

ListViews were designed for chatting! 
Here is [an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List12.html) of using this

It uses the `android:transcriptMode`

Here is a video [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=1928s) to understand this feature further

Answer (score 0):

Use the `public boolean pageDown (boolean bottom)` API.
Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pageDown%28boolean%29) for more on API.